# Socket.io - How to connect to a server through another server securely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redis, socket.io

I'm trying to build a game server which has separate lobbies

I'm trying to not allow any connections to my `Workers` directly, unless it's done through a **Manager**

Is this possible/good practice?

**Server Architecture**

[image: Server Architecture]

Client connects to `Manager` through a `Load Balancer`, he/she receives all files via Express, along with the list of lobbies, then chooses which "game lobby", then connects to that server/worker/lobby

***Connect to Manager***

```
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.5:8080');
```

***Then Connect to Worker***

```
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.5:2002');
```

If connection is not done through `Manager` => **block connection**